# ST_Intersects with multiple geometries

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I am just learning PostGIS and have a simple problem I can't get the answer for.

I want to select the geometries that intersect with given multiple geometries.

To make it simpler, let's say I want to select the line(s) which intersect with polygon**1** and polygon**2** in the image below.

I came up with something like this, but it's not working. What am I missing?

```
SELECT lines.id, lines.geom 
FROM lines, polygons 
WHERE(st_intersects(lines.geom,polygons.geom) and polygons.id = 1) and
     (st_intersects(lines.geom,polygons.geom) and polygons.id = 2)
```

[image: ???]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query does not work because it looks for single polygons having both id 1 and 2, which is not possible.

Instead, you could restrict the polygons to either `id 1 or 2`, then to intersects with the line and at last keep the lines having 2 intersections:

```sql
SELECT lines.id, lines.geom 
FROM lines
 JOIN polygons ON st_intersects(lines.geom,polygons.geom)
WHERE polygons.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY lines.id, lines.geom 
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Let's note that it would be more efficient to only select and group by ID, then to fetch the geom for these lines.